# Jersey PUT, POST methods don't recognize implementing entity

Tags: java, rest, jersey

## Problem

I'm generating a model and its API methods using [raml-to-jaxrs](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-for-jax-rs/blob/master/raml-to-jaxrs/README.md), more specifically [raml-for-jaxrs-cli](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-for-jax-rs/tree/master/raml-to-jaxrs/raml-to-jaxrs-cli).

My model has two generated classes, `Product` being an `interface` and `ProductImpl` its implementing class.

---

An example, with one of the API endpoint methods:

```
@Override
public PutProductsResponse putProducts(String xSessionToken, Product entity) {
```

- *method will not be called when I `PUT` a `ProductImpl` entity. It fails with a `500` response. This is unexpected behavior.*

*If I change it to:*

```
@Override
public PutProductsResponse putProducts(String xSessionToken, ProductImpl entity) {
```

- *method will be called, as usual.*

---

## I've Tried

- Calling the `GET` method (which does not capture any parameters aside from the `sessionToken`). It works.
- Replacing the expected `Product` interface for its `ProductImpl` implementing class (as shown in the example). It works.

  - But it's not a permanent solution since the endpoint methods must conform to the RAML-generated code.

---

## In-depth

I'm using *jersey 2.11* and *tyrus-container-grizzly-server 1.13* as Maven dependencies.

The error that is returned from the request is:

```
InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:9998/products, status=500, reason=Request failed.}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that interfaces does not have any instance variables .So there is no point in Unmarshalling it So . Iterfaces can't be used in place of POJO when you are sending request .

In time beginning.  POJO are not suppose to implement any iterface . This restriction has been remove now i don't see any harm in using ProductImpl in place of Product